# Trying to find GCD with Haskell. Where is the error in my code?

Tags: haskell, greatest-common-divisor

As an exercise, I'm trying to write this by myself but I'm stuck and don't know where the error is in my code.

```
module Hf where

--sumSquaresTo :: Integer -> Integer
--sumSquaresTo x = sum [ n^2 | n <- [1..x] ]

divides a b = b `mod` a == 0

divisors a = [n | n <- [1..a], n `divides` a ]


lnko :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
lnko a b = [n | n <- [1..max(a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b) ]
```

GHCI output:

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
                  with actual type `[a0 -> a0]'
    * In the expression:
        [n | n <- [1 .. max (a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b)]
      In an equation for `lnko':
          lnko a b
            = [n | n <- [1 .. max (a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b)]
   |
12 | lnko a b = [n | n <- [1..max(a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b) ]
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Integer -> a0'
                  with actual type `Integer'
    * The function `a' is applied to one argument,
      but its type `Integer' has none
      In the first argument of `max', namely `(a b)'
      In the expression: max (a b)
   |
12 | lnko a b = [n | n <- [1..max(a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b) ]
   |                              ^^^

error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> a0'
                  with actual type `Integer'
    * In the second argument of `divides', namely `a'
      In the first argument of `(&&)', namely `(n `divides` a)'
      In the expression: (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b)
    * Relevant bindings include
        n :: a0 -> a0
          (bound at C:\\Users\erdos\Desktop\haskell\hazi1.hs:12:17)
   |
12 | lnko a b = [n | n <- [1..max(a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b) ]
   |                                                  ^

error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> a0'
                  with actual type `Integer'
    * In the second argument of `divides', namely `b'
      In the second argument of `(&&)', namely `(n `divides` b)'
      In the expression: (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b)
    * Relevant bindings include
        n :: a0 -> a0
          (bound at C:\\Users\erdos\Desktop\haskell\hazi1.hs:12:17)
   |
12 | lnko a b = [n | n <- [1..max(a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b) ]
   |                                                                     ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: You don't need parens in `max(a b)`. Haskell uses “applicative notation” meaning that what you used to write as `max(a, b)` in other languages, becomes `max a b` here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, there are 2 mistakes.

1. In Haskell, you do not write `max(a b)`, but simply `max a b`. This is called [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).
2. Your function actually locates *all* common factors. For instance:

   ```
   λ lnko 8 16
   [1,2,4,8]
   ```

   If you amend the type signature accordingly, it will work. Or you may select one of the factors somehow.

Overall, this is great code. Keep going!

Comment: What is the shortcut for lambda symbol?

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero Ctrl+Shift+03bb, why?

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero Try putting `:set prompt "λ "` in your `~/.ghc/ghci.conf`. You will not be disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

The types do not match. Indeed, in your function:

```
lnko :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
lnko a b = [n | n <- [1..max(a b)], (n `divides` a) && (n `divides` b) ]
```

You here return a list, since you use list comprehension. Furthermore you made some syntactical errors. For example `max (a b)` means that you perform a function application with `a` as function, and `b` as parameter. This should be `max a b`.

You can rewrite this to:

```
lnko :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
lnko a b = maximum [n | n <- [1..min a b], n `divides` a, n `divides` b ]
```

But nevertheless, you here use a method where you iterate over all possible dividers, to find the largest one. You can for example use the [*Euclidean algorithm* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) which will usually outperform linear search:

```
lnko :: Integral i => i -> i -> i
lnko a 0 = a
lnko a b = lnko b (mod a b)
```

This will be more safe as well, for example if you use negative numbers in the parameters.

Comment: Actually this answer is better.